# How to dump goroutine of a container's entry point process?

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, goroutine

I have an application run by `docker-compose up`. When a stop the app by `docker-compose stop`, one of container doesn't terminate. The container run a process written in Go, so I want to dump goroutine of the process to see where the process is stuck.

I can `docker ps` to see the container, and `docker exec -it <container-id> bash` to enter the container, but once I `kill -QUIT <process id>`, as the process terminate, container stopped as well, so I cannot get goroutine dump.

How to get goroutine dump in this case?

Comment: If you have access to the source, you can use net/http/pprof to look at the goroutines and other things at runtime.

Comment: I'd expect diagnostics like this to go to the process's stderr; are they captured in the `docker-compose logs` of the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> container stopped as well, so I cannot get goroutine dump.

I think you can get the goroutine dump from the logs of the container, providing that:

1. `docker-compose stop` stops running containers without removing them;
2. `kill -QUIT <process id>` dumps the goroutine to the stderr.

Here is the docker command to get the container logs (`-n` specifies the number of lines to show from the end of the logs):

```
$ docker logs -n 1000 [container-name]
```